# Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.portfolio/.MainActivity }

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

When I use the command `npm start | npx react-native run-android` then my terminal freezes at this line:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 52s
100 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 98 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
8081
info Starting the app on "<ip address redacted>"... 
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]  cmp=com.portfolio/.MainActivity }
```

I tried this command:

```
npm start | npx react-native run-android
```